# What will be the antonym of "appreciate" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, antonyms

In Mumbai the value of properties has appreciated, but the quality of life has __________.

Can we use "depreciated" here?

Edit: The antonym needs to imply that the quality of life is not good anymore.

Comment: Please explain your doubts.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the quality of life is lower, or is less valued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not an antonym of ***appreciated***, but a verb which would be ***in contrast*** with it. Of ***decreased, declined, deteriorated*** [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quality%20of%20life%20has%20declined%2Cquality%20of%20life%20has%20deteriorated%2Cquality%20of%20life%20has%20decreased&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquality%20of%20life%20has%20declined%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquality%20of%20life%20has%20deteriorated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquality%20of%20life%20has%20decreased%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***deteriorated*** is more commonly used with *quality of life*.

It means

> to become worse:
>
> - As the company's financial outlook ***deteriorated***, several directors resigned. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deteriorate))

Gngram does not find any instances of "the quality of life has depreciated", and to use it would trigger a symmetry in meaning that is not so successful. The way in which the meaning of ***appreciated*** is connected to the value of properties is different from the way in which *depreciated* would be connected to *quality of life*. Plus, ***depreciate*** can also mean *to become cheaper* so the price with which you can *sell* something decreases:

> Our car ***depreciated*** (by) $1,500 in the first year we owned it. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/depreciate))

and this is not the meaning you wish to convey.